# Ajax post working but not callback message in Android browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

im implementing sign up with ajax on my site its working perfectly on desktop but causing problem in Android Browser The problem is after i click on signup button in android browser it post data to database but do not replace the html message.And alert native code error.

```
function postdata(){
    var chkfrm = checkdata();
    if(chkfrm == 0){
        var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Signup/signin';    
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#formI").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           beforeSend:function(){
               $("#signupdiv").html('<h1>Loadinng...........</h1>');
           },
           success:function(data)
           {
               $("#signupdiv").html(data);
           },
           error:function () {
                 alert(console.log);      
           }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $("#msgjava").html('<p>We need a little bit information from you.Please fill it.</p>');
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `e.preventDefault();` where you are because `e` is not passed into this function (thus it is undefined).  This will cause an error and stop JS execution.

In what you posted, you are also missing a closing brace at the end of the `postdata()` function.

---

Your alert says "native code" because that's what this line of code:

```
alert(console.log)
```

will do.  `console.log` is a native function so alerting a native function won't do anything useful.  You need to make that alert a lot more useful.  To see in more detail what error is coming back from the ajax function, change your error handler to something like this:

```
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("status = " + textStatus + ", errorThrown = " + errorThrown);
    }
```

And, then see what it says.

Comment: i removed the e.preventDefault(); and also added closing brace but still not working on android browser

Comment: @user2998659 - you will need to find out more about what the actual error is.  See the revised error handling function I've suggested.

Comment: status=error,errorThrown=Error:INVAID_STATE_ERR:DOM Exceprion 11

Comment: @user2998659 - I'm fairly sure that error means that when you do `$("#signupdiv").html(data);` you have invalid HTML in the `data` variable.